# How to extract the data files from folders and subfolders

Tags: c#

1. I am having a problem with reading the files and subfolders. My code reads fine for the given fixed source path, `E:\\Folder\\test\\test2`.
2. There are many folders in the test, like test2, test3, test4, etc. I want to extract the data files in the main folder, `test`.
3. For example, I want to extract the files in test, so I want to read all the files contained in the test instead of writing my code for test3, test4 and many. And I want to extract and write all the files as same source structure on another drive.
4. like, if the source structure is like `E:\\Folder\\test\\test2` then the destination structure should be like `C:\\Folder\\test\\test2`

Is there any way to do this?

Here is my code,

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    txtSelectedDate.Text = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    selectedDate = txtSelectedDate.Text;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime stdate = Datetimepicker1.value;
    while (stdate <= DateTime.Now)
    {
        txtSelectedDate.Text = stdate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        selectedDate = txtSelectedDate.Text;
        string DayBgSpot = "E:\\Folder\\test\\test2";
        string DayBgSpotDestination = "E:\\Folder1";
        int DT = int.Parse(txtSelectedDate.Text);
        FileReader Reader = new FileReader();
        FileReader Reader1 = new FileReader();
        Reader.OpenDirectory(DayBgSpot);
        Reader.ReadNaster();
        string path = DayBgSpotDestination + "\\" + txtSelectedDate.Text + ".txt";
        StreamWriter Strwriter = new StreamWriter(path);
        try
        {
            while (Reader.iMaRecordsLeft > 0)
            {
                string SecName = Reader.sMaSecName;
                string Symbol = Reader.sMaSecSymbol;
                Symbol = prefix + Symbol;
                int abc = 0;

                Reader.OpenSecurityByName(Reader.sMaSecName);
                if (Reader.iSeRecords > 0)
                {
                    while (Reader.iSeRecordsLeft > 0)
                    {
                        Reader.ReadDay();
                        float O = Reader.dSeo;
                        float H = Reader.dSeh;
                        float L = Reader.dSel;
                        float C = Reader.dSec;
                        double V = Reader.dSeV;
                        double OI = Reader.dSrest;
                        string T = Reader.iSeTime.ToString();
                        string D = Reader.iSeDate.ToString();
                        if (int.Parse(D) == DT)
                        {
                            string a = string.Concat(SecName, ",", Symbol, ",", D, ",", T, ",", O, ",", H, ",",  L, ",", C, ",", V, ",", OI);
                            if (SecName != "" && V != 0)
                            {
                                Strwriter.WriteLine(a);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                abc++;
                Reader.ReadNaster();
            }

            Reader.CloseDirectory();
            Strwriter.Close();
            Strwriter.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        stdate = stdate.AddDays (1); // It will get next date till present
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo baseFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Folder\test\");
string destinationPath = @"e:\Folder\test\";
System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = baseFolder.GetDirectories();
foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
{
   string subFolder = dirInfo.Name;
   System.IO.FileInfo[] fileInfos = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
   foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
   {
      // Do something with the files
      string writePath = destinationPath + subFolder + @"\" + fileInfo.Name;
      // Write
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.0 this is one line:

```
var filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(path: @"C:\", searchPattern: "*pattern*", searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Clearly, the root path and search pattern are not in line with the proposed sample, but my intention should clear.

I hope this helps